# How to use environment variables in GitLab Omnibus configuration

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have GitLab running on a Kubernetes cluster.

I have a ConfigMap containing all my omnibus configurations.
The ConfigMap gets mounted to the environment variable GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG.

This expose sensitive configurations like passwords in src code.

I'd like to create Secrets instead and mount them as additional Environment variables and have the 
omnibus config read from the additional Environment variables as in the example bellow.

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.hostedemail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "username@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = $SMTP_PASSWORD
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domain.com"
etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same issue with docker-compose and I resolved this by the Ruby ENV variable:

```yaml
  environment:
    SMTP_USER_PASSWORD: ${SMTP_PASSWORD}
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
      gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: That works even for nested data structures, like `gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = { 'aws_secret_access_key' => ENV['GITLAB_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] }`